# Nature of generalized integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am trying to find the nature of this generalized integral

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2\sin x}{e^x \ln x}dx$$

I tried absolute convergence then comparison but didn't work since I found $\frac{x^2}{e^x \ln x}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Break the integral into
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2sin x}{e^x ln x}dx=\int_1^e \frac{x^2sin x}{e^x ln x}dx+\int_e^\infty \frac{x^2sin x}{e^x ln x}dx$$
The second integral is convergent compared to $x^2e^{-x}$ and for the first one, the function is $\sim {1^2\times \sin 1\over e^1\ln x}$. Now what are the natures of
$$
\int_1^e{dx\over \ln x}
$$
and
$$
\int_e^\infty{x^2e^{-x}dx}
$$?

Comment: thank you, but why the first integral is equivalent to $\frac{1^2\times sin 1}{e^1 ln x}$

Comment: I should have mentioned that this equivalence is for $x$s that are sufficiently close to $1$, that is, the integral should have been $\int_1^{1+\epsilon}$ instead of $\int_1^e$. The reason is now simple since $x^2,\sin x,e^x$ tend to $1,\sin1 ,e$ respectively.